# Unable to disable flyway via spring.flyway.enabled

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

I use flyway for my local profile to populate a DB for integration tests.

`application.yml`:

```yaml
spring:
  (...)
  flyway.enabled: false
```

`application-local.yml`:

```yaml
spring:
  (...)
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    license-key: (...)
    locations: classpath:mssql/migrations
```

## Expected:

App doesn't try to autoconfigure flyway during startup with profile `dev`

## Actual:

```java
The following profiles are active: dev
(...)
org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext
    Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
    (...)
    Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationScriptMissingException: 
    Cannot find migration scripts in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migration scripts or check your Flyway configuration)
```

## Versions:

flyway-core 6.3.1
spring boot 2.2.5

Comment: Please show how you configure spring profiles

Answer (score 0):

You specified `application-local.yml` and it means that you specified `local` profile but you run the application with `dev` profile. There are two potential issues:

1. You run the app with the wrong profile: should be `local` instead of
   `dev`
2. Or you don't include `local` profile to `dev` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Answer (score 0):

You had error in your default config (application.yml) file:

Should be something like this:

```
spring:
 flyway:
  enabled: false
```